# C++: Optimizations made on wrapped methods that are trivial

Tags: c++, optimization, wrapper

When I write wrapper classes, a lot of the methods take the following form:

```
class Wrapper{
    public:
        vec3 getPos(){          return m_position.get();  }
        void setPos(vec3 pos){  m_position.set(pos);      }
    private:
        ThingGettingWrapped m_position;
    }
}
```

I was curious however, will `getPos()` and `setPos()` incur overhead, or are modern compilers smart enough to optimize the delegation away so `wrapper.set/get()` is equivalent to `wrapper.m_thingWrapped.set/get()`?

(I know the methods are inlined in my example, but assume they are not explicitly inlined and defined separately)

Comment: Wrappers are so common any optimizer that failed to optimize away the overhead you are asking about could hardly be called an "optimizer".  Unless I misunderstood what you are saying with "defined separately":  If the optimizer can't see that the definition is a trivial wrapper, it can't optimize it.  "Explicitly inlined" doesn't matter.  If the optimizer can see the definition, it can inline the function.

Comment: 1. Download a modern compiler. 2. See for yourself. 3. There's no step 3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An optimizer *can* expand the call inline in which case there is no overhead for the extra call.

A wrapper like that *can* incur overhead if the call is not expanded inline.

Optimizers of modern compilers do inline expansion.

> assume they are not explicitly inlined and defined separately

There *will* be (small) overhead unless the optimizer can expand the call inline. You can guarantee the ability to inline by calling the function in the same translation unit where it was defined. Defining the function inline - like you did in your example - enables and enforces this for all translation units because inline functions are defined in all of them. Another way to allow inline expansion across translation units is [LTO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interprocedural_optimization).

A function is not required to be inline in order for it to be expandable inline and an optimizer is not required to inline-expand all calls to inline functions. A function that is inline will always be expandable inline. A function that is not inline may be expandable in some case, but not always.

Answer (score 1):

These functions will get inlined by the compiler as long as some simple rules are followed:

1. They are not virtual (they aren't in your case, but could be in some other place) - compiler often can't inline virtual functions - because it would render the whole idea of virtual functions useless.
2. The actual implementation of the function is available to the compiler during the compilation of the source calling `getPos`. Again, it would not be possible to compile the example code, but you could declare `getPos` and `setPos` as member functions without giving them a body in the class, in which case the compiler won't (necessarily) be able to inline them. [1]

[1] Compilers that support Link Time Optimisation (LTO) or Whole Program Optimisation as some compiler vendors like to call it can inline functions even if the source is not available - this is because final code-generation isn't done until later, so a half-compiled version of the source is stored in the object file. In my experience, LTO is not used for most projects.

Comment: I don't agree with 2. gcc and msvc++ will inline them even if they are exist in a seperate file.

Comment: Only with LTO, which in my experience isn't used as much as it possibly could.

Comment: `-funit-at-a-time ` in gcc, when used with multiple files, allows the optimizer to get information from all the translation units while optimizing. Wouldn't that allow inline expansion across translation units even without LTO, as long as all units (the one where the function is defined, and all where it's used) are compiled at the same time? Or am I mistaken?

Comment: Seems like `-funit-at-a-time` does nothing in modern versions of gcc?

Comment: @MatsPetersson ah, apparently the option does nothing now. But perhaps the effects that it had are now always enabled?

Comment: It DID "parse the entire compilation unit" (in other words, one .c or .cpp file) before beginning code-generation. Which may well be enabled by default now. It doesn't help for inlining if the function is in a separate .c or .cpp file tho'. It MAY help if you declare the function later than the call to it.